# Is there any way to get full page ads on my app besides just banners from admob on android?

Tags: android, admob, banner

i have a bunch of banners in my app as ads but i want to add different ones or a full paged ad.  Is this possible or do you get payed more?

also so far i have like about a 1000 requests on my admob account, when do i start seeing any kind of money?

Comment: please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

For admob you need to be contacted by Google before you can run paid interstitials.

Other ad networks also provide interstitials, for instance greystripe or AppBrain AppLift: http://www.appbrain.com/info/developers and you don't need approval for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are full page ads. They're called [interstitials](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/advanced).

Comment: do you get paid more per imression?